# Nested Routing on exported components with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I was following a CRUD tutorial that used nested Routes like the code below. I tried to omit most of the code that doesn't concern routing.

After looking up several other tutorials on nested routing I noticed they don't use exported components like I was. I also noticed that the tutorial code below exported its components using withRouter.

**index.js:**

```
...imports

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
       <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**App.js:**

```
const App = ({ classes }) => (
     <CssBaseline />
     <AppHeader />
     <main className={classes.main}>
       <Home />
       <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
       <Route exact path="/posts" component={PostManager} /> //This renders a list of posts
     </main>
   </Fragment>
```

**PostsManager.js:**

```
...imports

...constructor and other functions (this.savePost)

  renderPostEditor = ({ match: { params: { id } } }) => {
    if (this.state.loading) return null;
    const post = find(this.state.posts, { id: Number(id) });

    if (!post && id !== 'new') return <Redirect to="/posts" />;

    return <PostEditor post={post} onSave={this.savePost} />;
  };

  render() { //component render funciton
        ...
        <Button
          variant="fab"
          color="secondary"
          aria-label="add"
          className={classes.fab}
          component={Link}
          to="/posts/new"
        >
        <Route exact path="/posts/:id" render={this.renderPostEditor} />
  }
 ...exporting component withRouter()
```

The problem I got was that when I tried to access `/posts/new` or `/posts/2` which both should match `/posts/:id`, I didn't get any match. The method this.renderPostEditor obviously didn't get called and PostEditor wasn't rendered.

I tried to solve the problem by removing the Route in PostsManager.js and putting in App.js. That way I got a match but it didn't render the way I wanted because this.renderPostEditor dependended on PostManager.js

My question is why I didn't get a match inside PostsManager.js but got match in App.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `exact` prop from `<Route ... />` definition.

Comment: And if you replace `render={this.renderPostEditor}` with something simple like `render={() => <span>foo</span>}`, still no luck?

Comment: Still, no match.

Comment: I took the `exact` prop out of `<Route exact path="/posts" component={PostsManager} />` in App.js instead of PostsManager.js and it worked. Thank you!